# why react javascript const object's members can be modified

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

As [here](https://www.educative.io/courses/road-to-react-with-class-components/B89ERoBzg0k) shows

```
// allowed
const helloWorld = {
  text: 'Welcome to the Road to learn React'
};
helloWorld.text = 'Bye Bye React';
```

works.

But why `helloworld`, as a constant object, its member can be modified? what is essentially `const` mean in react javascript?

Comment: Also arrays …the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value.

when you are assigning an object to a const. you are creating a reference to that object.

```
const helloWorld = {
   text: 'Welcome to the Road to learn React'
};
```

Now const **helloWorld** does not know about the implementation or inner structure what it is holding. Javascript just has told to "helloWorld" that "**I am giving you this object, hold it. and Listen!!! man!!!,, you are not supposed to hold anything else**".

So, helloWorld does the same.
it holds the same object. But people can change the inner parts of the object.

Hence,

People can do following:

```
helloWorld.text = 'Bye Bye React';
```

Here helloWorld is still holding the same object. hellowWorld will allow you  to do anything with what it is holding. But, what it won't do is: "it won't drop it"

So, people can not do following:

```
helloWorld = "something else";
```

People cannot ask to helloWorld to hold something else.

Answer (score 1):

Const will define a object no reassignable but we can edit properties in the object. Using const won't change the structure of the object.